# ResetField in Java

Tags: java

i am getting error while i pressed button reset in java. Update: I already create a JTextField and JPasswordField which is textField1 and passwordField1 in LoginForm.java in the design view, the thing is i want access both of it in the ResetField.java .

here is my code:

```
public class ResetField 
{
    JTextField textField1;
    JPasswordField passwordField1;

    public void ResetAction()
    {
        textField1.setText("");
        passwordField1.setText("");
    }
}

private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        _resetField.ResetAction();
    }
```

Here is the error text:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.ResetField.ResetAction(ResetField.java:17)
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.LoginForm.button2ActionPerformed(LoginForm.java:170)
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.LoginForm.access$100(LoginForm.java:10)
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.LoginForm$2.actionPerformed(LoginForm.java:73)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Unreadable. Could you please include the top few lines of the error as text?

Comment: Copy and paste the errors, that image is too hard to read.

Comment: You can delete image now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just creating a reference but not creating an object.`passwordField1` is a reference not an object.Similarly `textField1` is a reference not an object.
create an object like this `JTextField textField1=new JTextField()`;

public class ResetField 
{
    JTextField textField1;
    JPasswordField passwordField1;

```
public void ResetAction()
{
    textField1=new JTextField();
     passwordField1=new JPasswordField();
    textField1.setText("");
    passwordField1.setText("");
}
}

private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        _resetField.ResetAction();
    }
```

Comment: Hai, i already create the JTextField in the design view, but i want to access it in another class. Let's say i create a JTextField as textField1 in the LoginForm.java, but i want to access that textField1 in the ResetField.java  . JTextField is public

Comment: @Kaoru try with my updated code and let me know if it works or not

Comment: there is no error sir, when i run the program, the reset button is not executing

Comment: @Kaoru Earlier you were getting some error(error shown in your question) and now you are not getting that error,right?

Comment: yeah, it is correct. but now the function is not running (not execute)

Comment: @Kaoru so this means my answer is exactly according to your question.So you can accept this answer

Comment: @Kaoru try to print something when you this method

Comment: @rocking `try catch` also fix the problem but is not right solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate your objects. Right now, `textField1` and `passwordField1` are just null references. Instead of this:

```
JTextField textField1;
JPasswordField passwordField1;
```

You need this:

```
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
JPasswordField passwordField1 = new JPasswordField();
```

Comment: Hai, i already create the JTextField in the design view, but i want to access it in another class. Let's say i create a JTextField as textField1 in the LoginForm.java, but i want to access that textField1 in the ResetField.java . JTextField is public

Comment: Better is to have one comment (not duplicated on all answers) and better is to have one field (not duplicated in many classes) :)

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   inspection.management.system.ResetField.ResetAction(ResetField.java:17)

Why you used `_resetField` with `resetAction`

```
 private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ResetAction();// Remove _resetField.
 }
```

Also you need to initiate following fields.

```
JTextField textField1=new JTextField();
JPasswordField passwordField1=new JPasswordField();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how variables work.  textField1 and passwordField1 are declared inside your class.  That means they can only be accessed from inside your class.  Even if they were public you would still need an instance of the containing class to reference them.

You created textField1 and passwordField1 in more than one class but that does not make them the same.  If you want to be able to reference the exact JTextField and JPasswordField in your GUI from another class, you must pass a reference to it.

```
public class ResetField 
{
    JTextField textField1;
    JPasswordField passwordField1;

    public void ResetAction(JTextFile textField, JPasswordFiled passwordField)
    {
        textField1 = textField;
        passwordField1 = passwordField;
        textField1.setText("");
        passwordField1.setText("");
    }
}
```

That said, you do not need a new class in order to reset those fields in the constructor.  You should instead create a method in the class that contains your fields and reset them there.